# Does Android use sparse files similar to Bluestacks?

Tags: android, bluestacks

I have `Bluestacks` installed on my windows8 machine and I was poking around its files and folder structure. I see that in `Bluestacks`, app data is stored under `Android/Data.sparsefs/Store` or `Android/SDCard.sparsefs/Store`

How similar is this to the actual Android OS? Does the OS have the same folder structure and/or sparse files? (or roughly the same) If not, what is the difference and how does the Android structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

When you install an application you have this folder:

```
/data/data/"your package name"
```

example:

```
/data/data/myappexample
```

Use the DDMS to access for your Emulator.

inside this path you have:

```
databases/:  databases
lib/: libraries for the app
files/: other related files
shared_prefs/: preferences and settings
cache/: caches
```

Comment: is there a reason why the first /data is highlighted in red? is it suppose to be a placeholder for some dynamic name? or just a stackoverflow thing?

Comment: i dont know why is red,  is not dynamic... only the "package name" change for your real package name